# Fix Self referral issue in GA4 property

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Our GA4 property in Google analytics is showing our own website as a referral source. Normaly, in ga3 property there is a filter where you can exclude sites like payment portals and such. In the new property this feature is not yet available.

We tried using the following script to workaround the problem

```
  var ref = {{Referrer}};
  // don't bother if there is no referrer
  if (!ref) return ref;

  var newref;

  // place your external referrers here (domain names)
  // adding 'foo.bar.com' matches 'www.foo.bar.com' too
  var domains = [
    // banks
    'rabobank.nl', 'ing.nl', 'abnamro.nl', 'regiobank.nl', 'snsbank.nl',
    'asnbank.nl', 'triodos.nl', 'vanlanschot.nl', 'knab.nl', 'bunq.com',
    'frieslandbank.nl', 'snsreaal.nl', 'secure-ing.com',
    
    // payment providers, cards, foreign banks
    'mollie.nl', 'mollie.com', 'paypal.com', 'paypal.nl', 'adyen.com',
    'multisafepay.com', 'visa.com', 'wlp-acs.com', 'belfius.be', 'payin3.nl',
    'icscards.nl', 'arcot.com', 'securesuite.co.uk', 'hsbc.com.hk',
    'cm-cic.com', 'pay.nl', 'redsys.es', 'tatrabanka.sk'
  ];

  
  domains.forEach(function(x) {
    // loop through domains, 
    if(ref.match(RegExp('^https?://([^.]+\.)?'+ x +'/')))
      newref = x;
  })

  // return referrer, or the new one
  return newref ?
    'https://' + {{Page Hostname}} + '/excluded-referrer/' + newref
    : ref
}
```

The script does not work though. Could you give me any new recommendation on how to solve this issue or tell me if the code might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with GA 4 and unfortunately have not found a solution for it yet. It seems to be a major problem with GA 4 and is also making conversion tracking in Google Ads campaigns impossible.

Comment: It has made the adoption of the ga4 property impossible. Our website is top channel.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Google actually releases gradually a referral exclusion feature in GA4, which you can find here:https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10327750?ck_subscriber_id=750579406

Thankfully this will help with this problem.